# How to count frequency of amno acids of different proteins from one FASTA file with bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, bioinformatics, fasta

how I have to write a script, which can count frequency of amino acids of different proteins,which are in one file? 
For example:

```
Fasta file is

>Protein1 info
ATCGGGCTGC
>Protein2 info
ATCGGGCTGCGGCC
>Protein2 info
ATCGGGCTGCGGCCCCC
.............


I have to get :
Protein 1
A:10% T:20% G:40% C:30%
Protein 2
A:7.143% T: 14,286 G: 42,858 C:35,715
...............
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry for edits! Here is a working version finally, with double precision:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Let's read the file passed as an argument to this script
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    # We check if this line have ">" character in the beginning. That is, if it is the line with amino acids or with protein name
    if [[ $(echo ${line} | head -c 1) == ">" ]]; then
        # We print out the protein name
        echo ${line} | awk {'print $1'}
        # next=1 means that the amino acids will be in the next line, not this line, this is just the line with protein name
        next=1
    fi
    # We do the code below only if it is the line with amino acids, so when next is not 1, but 0
    if [[ $next == 0 ]] ; then
        # We need to have the number of all amino acids to count percentage, so we count the number of all characters
        all=${#line}
        # And number of amino acids A in this protein, that is the number of "A" characters
        A=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"A" '{print NF-1}')
        # Amino acids T, then C and G
        T=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"T" '{print NF-1}')
        C=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"C" '{print NF-1}')
        G=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F"G" '{print NF-1}')
        # Now let's count what percentage of all amino acids (all characters) are amino acids A (characters "A"). Change scale=2 to scale=3 to increase precision and have 3 digits after the dot, not two
        Apercentage=`bc -l <<< "scale=2; 100*${A}/${all}"`
        # Same for T, C and G
        Tpercentage=`bc -l <<< "scale=2; 100*${T}/${all}"`
        Gpercentage=`bc -l <<< "scale=2; 100*${G}/${all}"`
        Cpercentage=`bc -l <<< "scale=2; 100*${C}/${all}"`
        # We print out calculated percentage of amino acids
        printf "A: %s%% T: %s%% G: %s%% C: %s%%\n" "${Apercentage}" "${Tpercentage}" "${Gpercentage}" "${Cpercentage}"
    fi
    # We reset the "next"
    next=0
done < "$1"
```

Now this is the test file named "fasta":

```
>Protein1 info
ATCGGGCTGC
>Protein2 info
ATCGGGCTGCGGCC
>Protein2 info
ATCGGGCTGCGGCCCCC
```

And the output:

```
[user@host ]$ ./script.sh fasta 
>Protein1
A: 10.00% T: 20.00% G: 40.00% C: 30.00%
>Protein2
A: 7.14% T: 14.28% G: 42.85% C: 35.71%
>Protein2
A: 5.88% T: 11.76% G: 35.29% C: 47.05%
```

Numbers are correct. One-liners of mosvy and PaulRM accumulate all "As" and "Ts" and "Gs" from previous proteins (or do some other thing wrong). They do not calculate percentage properly I am afraid. Only the first protein got the right numbers in their one-liners, the next proteins got wrong numbers:

```
Protein1
A: 10% T: 20% G: 40% C: 30% 
Protein2
A: 14.2857% T: 28.5714% G: 71.4286% C: 57.1429% 
Protein2
A: 17.6471% T: 35.2941% G: 94.1176% C: 94.1176%
```

Comment: A single instance of `awk` can already process the entire file - that is what `awk` does, fast and well. Why on Earth would you start 3 or 4 `awk` processes and 3 `bc` processes for every single line?

Comment: Mark: You are right, it's not optimal. But I am not sure how I could assign four variables A, T, C and G to the right values with using one instance of awk. Feels like I am missing something. mosvy: I actually accidentally saw this. Now I think that your script is more handy than mind when fixed. Nice one-liner :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be bash?

```
perl -nle 'print($1), next if /^> *(\S+)/; next unless $l=length; my %h; $h{$_}++ for split ""; print join " ", map sprintf("%s: %g%%", $_, $h{$_}*100/$l), qw(A T G C)'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
gawk -v FS=""  '/>/ { print $0 ; next } {  split($0, chars, "")  ; i=length($0) ; for(x in chars) {  a[chars[x]]++  } ; for(x in a) printf  x ":" ( a[x] * 100 / i) "% " ; print ""  }'  Fasta
```

Comment: Why do you split `$0` ? Setting `FS` to null char already does that